# How to extract date by id & status

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have a table like this

```
Id status date 
1 a 2022-01-01 
1 b 2022-02-01 
1 c 2022-03-01 
1 d 2022-04-01 
2 c 2022-01-01 
2 b 2022-02-01 
2 a 2022-03-01 
2 g 2022-04-01
```

The data is ordered by `id` & `date`. I’d like to get

```
Id date  
1 2022-03-01 
2 2022-03-01
```

where the date is the one that follows immediately after the status b.
Or what is the same minimum date among the statuses following status b
and the statuses are not sequential

Comment: Use a derived table/CTE and `LAG`?

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: `lead` and `lag` seem to be what you're looking for.

Comment: @lemon just group by but it does not solve the problem

Comment: LEAD function gives you the next row. LAG is the previous one.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select   id
        ,min(date) as date
from     (
         select  id
                ,case status when 'b' then lead(date) over(partition by id order by date) end as date
         from    t
         ) t
group by id
```

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-03-01 |
| 2 | 2022-03-01 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nh1C6NGw)

Comment: The aggregation seems like an odd way to do this, if I am honest. Why not just a `WHERE`  on `status` from the derived table

Comment: because the op asked for a minimum result per id. I know the data doesn't reflect it. I had a where clause orginially.